# Delphi android application is raising issue in Lennova A5000 mobile

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I'm using Delphi 10 Seattle trail version for developing mobile application. And I tried to create new android mobile application which contains only TEditBox. And then compiled by setting the option as "Release". Then, generated the .apk file and then provided the file to the user. And when the user tried to click the edit box, the application raises the error message that "**The Appname is not responding**".

The user is using the **Lennova A5000** and the Os is Android 5.0.2.

And the same application is running in my Moto g2 (5.0.2) and Micromax Yureka.
Please provide me is there any solution.

Also, I have updated the app in google app store. Then, it is showing as **incompatible application for this device** (Lennova A5000).

And also I have updated all the android SDK packages. After that also, it is raising the same issue.

I think this may be problem to Embarcadreo Delphi or any missing packages? *Dont know what to do.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'the application raises the error message that "the application is not responding".'. That is a contradiction.

Comment: ** "AppName"  is not responding**  is the error raised when the user clicked the Edit box.

Comment: I think you meant that he is using a Lenovo A5000? http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_a5000-7167.php

Comment: Yeah. The android version number is 5.0.2. And till now there is no problem in other android devices. I think this is a problem raised by Embarcadreo. And I have debugged this. And please provide me any solution

Comment: And one more thing, if the app contains the button, then the user can able to click the button. The problem is raising only in TEdit, TMemo.

Comment: You should inform and ask help from Embarcadero. They have a forum and a bug report site.

Comment: Yeah. I have done that also. [Embarcadreo Forum for this issue](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=769857&#769857)

Comment: Also I will try to install XE8 and then provide the apk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atlast I got the solution from Embarcadreo website. Please follow the mentioned steps.

1.Copy FMX.Platform.Android.pas to the project folder from source/fmx folder
and add the copied files to the project.

2. Then, do the changes in the following procedures.

**procedure TPlatformAndroid.RunOnUIThread(Proc: TThreadProcedure);**

```
procedure TPlatformAndroid.RunOnUIThread(Proc: TThreadProcedure);
begin
  //MainActivity.runOnUiThread(TSimpleProcedureRunner.Create(Proc));
  CallInUIThread(
  procedure()
  begin
    Proc;
  end);
end;
```

**procedure TPlatformAndroid.SynchronizeOnUIThread(Proc: TThreadProcedure);**

```
procedure TPlatformAndroid.SynchronizeOnUIThread(Proc: TThreadProcedure);
var
  Runner: TSimpleProcedureRunner;
begin
//  CallInUIThread(
//  procedure()
//  begin
//  Runner := TSimpleProcedureRunner.Create(Proc);
//  MainActivity.runOnUiThread(Runner);
//  Runner.Event.WaitFor;
//  end);
  CallInUIThreadAndWaitFinishing(
  procedure()
  begin
    Proc;
  end);
end;
```

**procedure TPlatformAndroid.SetClipboard(Value: TValue);**

```
procedure TPlatformAndroid.SetClipboard(Value: TValue);
var
  Setter: TClipboardSetter;
begin
  Setter := TClipboardSetter.Create(Value.ToString);
  CallInUIThread(
  procedure()
  begin
  SharedActivity.runOnUiThread(Setter);
  end);
  Setter.Done.WaitFor(INFINITE);
end;
```

**function TPlatformAndroid.GetClipboard: TValue;**

```
function TPlatformAndroid.GetClipboard: TValue;
var
  Getter: TClipboardGetter;
begin
  Getter := TClipboardGetter.Create;
  CallInUIThread(
  procedure()
  begin
  SharedActivity.runOnUiThread(Getter);
  end);
  Getter.Done.WaitFor(INFINITE);
  Result := Getter.Value;
end;
```

3. Then, Rebuild the project. After doing this every thing is working fine.

Comment: Where is TPlatformAndroid.SetClipboard and TPlatformAndroid.GetClipboard. I cannot found TClipboardGetter

Comment: I haven't needed to do the changes to SetClipboard and GetClipboard (which have been moved to FMX.Clipboard.Android) as yet. Fingers crossed ;-)