# Android app crashes when TEdit or TMemo gets focus

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

Make a new blank Multi-device Application. Put *Edit* or *Memo* on the Form. Build project on tablet Lenovo Tab 2 A8-50LC (Android version **5.0.2**).
When I touch Edit or Memo then error appears:
**call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)**
[image]

and app crashes. The same problem if I use

```
Edit1.SetFocus;
```

On a phone with Android 4.2 the application works without any problem.

Comment: I think we need to see some code.

Comment: @KristyWelsh, there is no code involved.

Comment: @Rusland, this seems to be a bug. But first, check if your device is supported with the [syscheck app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ss.syscheck&hl=en) .

Comment: For more details about hardware support, you can check out [this page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development).

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the Keyboard on Lenovo devices running Lollipop (5.X.X), however there is a workaround available.

[Delphi android application is raising issue in Lennova A5000 mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595492/delphi-android-application-is-raising-issue-in-lennova-a5000-mobile)

Comment: Excelent. That's what I need.