# Delphi 10.1 Berlin android 5.0.1 app crash on TEdit focus

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a minimal firemonkey test app with one button and one TEdit 
control on form.

If I run this app on Acer Tablet B1-770 on Andoid 5.0.1 happen
following:

If I click (or touch) in the edit control the app crashes.
I have no problems with other android versions.

Tried this solution but with no success (but this was for seattle version)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595492/delphi-android-application-is-raising-issue-in-lennova-a5000-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595492/delphi-android-application-is-raising-issue-in-lennova-a5000-mobile%20%20Thanks%20in%20advance%20for%20help)

Some suggestions? Thanks

Comment: First: The link doesn't work. Ich have the same problem with this Android version and a Acer Iconia tablet. This problem was reported several times in QC. Have a look at this [report](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9720). There seems to be a fix, but I had no time to look at it.

Comment: If you haven't added any of your own code then it must be a bug in either the RTL or Firemonkey.  Using the debugger would help you narrow it down but with nothing else to go on there isn't much to suggest other than to [file a QP report](https://quality.embarcadero.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) with Emba.

Comment: Thanks Kerem, sorry for the link (with manual copy/paste work). Your report link is exactly my same problem, reported to QP Embarcadero.